# Controlling and copying text from another application in Windows CE

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've been using a windows CE application that produces a text in its textbox when its button was clicked. I need this text for my C# app. How can I trigger its button and copy its text to my application.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "\\Program Files\\kangkong\\Barcode2005.exe";
            myProcess.Start();

            // minimize Barcode2005.exe and the code goes here...


        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Anyway, I'm using C# in Windows CE

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to your other question [c# how to get handle over a specific mainmenu using coredll.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143216/c-sharp-how-to-get-handle-over-a-specific-mainmenu-using-coredll-dll/26154382#26154382)

You need to define some p/invokes to be able to use the native FindWindow, GetWindowText functions.

First use FindWindow with the class name and/or title of the foreign window to get a handle to the main window. You may also use the processID (pID) to identify the foreign window.
Then enumerate all child windows of the main window until you find the window of the textbox (in native API an TextBox is using the EDIT class and is just a window like everything else you see). Then you can use GetWindowText using the found handle of the EDIT window.

If the foreign window is a dialog, you have to add GetDlgItem to your p/invoke list. Then you can use the EDIT dlg item's control ID to identify the input field and then use GetWindowText using this handle. AFAIR the control IDs are available in the resources of an windows exe file (use ResHacker to get the IDs).

BTW: where comes barcode2005.exe come from? Can you upload a copy for analysis? Is this a barcode graphic generator or decoder? If so, there are easier ways to get barcode graphics or decodes in C#.